# Why does Uniswap V3 use ticks [-887272,887272] to represent the price range [0,∞]?

Tags: liquidity-provider, uniswapv3, math

When providing liquidity to an already-created Uniswap V3 pool, you are offered the option to provide liquidity across the price range [0,∞] (effectively performing as a Uniswap V2 LP position). My question is why is the created LP position assigned a `tickLower` of `-887272` and `tickUpper` of `887272`? I'm interested in why those specific tick values were chosen to represent the price range [0,∞].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Uniswap V3, the formula for calculating the price from a given tick is the following:

[image]

By looking up Uniswap V3's codebase, we find that the price is represented by the variable `sqrtPriceX96` of type `uint160`. Where:

[image]

And:

[image]

By using both formulas above and plugging in the maximum tick value of `887272`, we find the following:

[image]

[image]

We know that in Solidity, the conventional way of representing the value of ∞ would be to use the maximum integer value allowed by a type. The max number we could obtain with a `uint160`(i.e. the type of `sqrtPriceX96`) is:

[image]

Therefore, we conclude that the chosen maximum tick of `887272` is just enough to produce a `sqrtPriceX96` that is still lower than the maximum value allowed by the type `uint160`. And most likely, the minimum tick value of `-887272` was chosen to represent a price of zero for symmetry.